# `0a1` in the output of diff file1 and file2

Tags: bash

Upon comparing two files and get the result:

```
 diff alpha_rsa.pub authorized_keys
0a1
> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBj3chjFnpxtHfeSUJVFv6fIN4CPZmIlBzuhMOOJNpovQqBc5JAhrz9uRiQIMHPD2vW+QJYiK08+6pCHthQSFrSLokLXTJfqEvb+frNEc6HvPPglGY3//97lbxR+CQYTjB/XgvnrP8sWKRt4VLfCwtCE6TqdVMx1y9SUmf7FghbHWhUioezdJaFJmfR+WVtELrUSwsc5eXcF+RS74eXEys2/v7LJF2JNYZxu0+Et7EwgxliA/5bOo6jTKBSZttBZPlsn2N7/GXnDilfAy06Iuc8MzMFCrAajQx8Nd4DG5Y33YyNVfU7eat9btUqNhpKGC+b5FGY4mkIPA2tammnjkx
```

I am aware that the output is the difference.

What does `0a1` mean? which cannot be found from the manual.

Comment: The official documentation is provided via the `info` system - in particular, type `info diffutils Normal` and then navigate to the `Detailed Normal` menu item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After line ***0*** (i.e., beginning) of the first file, ***a*** dd the following line (***1*** st line from the second file).

Note: Since these are *e*d commands, you should look at the *ed* man page: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man1/ed.1plan9.html

Also, google `diff command tutorial` for more examples.

Comment: could you please leave a reference manual.

Comment: Added to the answer